# Port based NAT-ing with iptables

Tags: linux, centos, iptables

On `eth0` port we have public IP, and `eth1` we have IP `10.31.0.1` which provides DHCP and Squid service.

Ports 8080,53,67,80,443 are open. Now for an application we have to open 1521,8443 ports so that it can hit remote server 1521,8443 ports.

But only opening port is not helping us connect to remote server. So we need to enable NAT for this specific port request. By what `iptable` commands can we accomplish port based NAT-ing?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read some documentation, as netfilter/iptables can be tricky. [Here](http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/index.html) are some good docs, even if a bit outdated.

For what you need to do, you need to add a rule in the nat table, before it gets to the routing code, hence the PREROUTING. This is because after the routing decision, it has already decided that the packet was for your router and not the real server.

You'll need something like this:

```
# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1521 -i eth0 \
  -j DNAT --to 5.6.7.8:1521
```

Replacing that with the IP address of the machine that will receive the packets.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Enable IP forwarding in the kernel:

   `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`
2. Flush the forwarding rules:

   `iptables -F FORWARD`
3. Set so only specific ports are NAT'd from this LAN IP range:

   `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -s 10.31.0.0/16 -p tcp --dports 1521,8443 MASQUERADE`